# Getting 404 error on API PUT call with route param

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack, angular-http

This is the API url I'm trying to hit in my *Express* app:

```
// Dashboard API to update account
app.post('/api/accounts/:id', accountsController.update);
```

[image]

**My full accounts module with Accounts factory, then specific descriptions below that:**

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module('app-accounts',
    ['ngAnimate', 'ngResource', 'account-directives'])

    .controller('AcctCtrl',
        ['$scope', '$resource', 'Accounts',
        function($scope, $resource, Accounts) {

        var vm = $scope;
            vm.$parent.modal = false;

        var Account = $resource('/api/accounts');

        // Open the edit account modal:
        this.editAccount = function(id, label, address) {
            console.log(id);
            vm.dash.modal = true;
            Accounts.modalEditAccount(vm.dash, id, label, address);
        };

        vm.dash.updateAccount = function(i) {
            console.log(i);
            // Call Update method from Accounts factory
            Accounts.update(i, $scope.new_label, $scope.new_address);
        }
    }])

    // Accounts factory (open edit model, get all, update, remove):
    .factory('Accounts', ['$http', '$resource', function($http, $resource) {

        var accountsFactory = {};

        accountsFactory.modalEditAccount = function(vm, id, label, address) {
            vm.modal_edit_account = true;
            vm.acct_id = id;
            vm.acct_label = label;
            vm.acct_address = address;
            vm.save_btn_text = 'save';
        };

        // Get all the accounts
        accountsFactory.all = function() {
            return $http.get('/api/stuff');
        };

        // Updates an account
        accountsFactory.update = function(id) {
            return $http.put('/api/accounts/'+id);
        };

        // Delete account
        accountsFactory.remove = function(id) {
            return $http.delete('/api/accounts/'+id);
        };

        return accountsFactory;

    }]);

})();
```

The `updateAccounts` function gets the `id` of the selected account and passes it into the update function in the `Accounts` factory:

```
vm.dash.updateAccount = function(i) {
    console.log(i);
    // Call Update method from Accounts factory
    Accounts.update(i, $scope.new_label, $scope.new_address);
}
```

Next inside my `Accounts` factory, here is the PUT/UPDATE method:

```
// Updates an account
accountsFactory.update = function(id) {
    return $http.put('/api/accounts/'+id);
};

// ^ call is to "/api/accounts/acct-1"
```

Then again my Express API update route:

```
// Dashboard API to update account
app.post('/api/accounts/:id', accountsController.update);
```

And finally my `accounts-controller.j` on the server:

```
module.exports = {
    create: function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
    },

    update: function(req, res) {
        console.log(req.body);
    }
};
```

Any thoughts on why I'm getting the 404?
`PUT http://localhost:9999/api/accounts/acct-2 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `app.post('/api/accounts/:id', accountsController.update);`

It should be `app.put`